# Unity! Вопрос по кнопкам и префабам с которыми они должны взаимодействовать

Tags: unity3d, button, prefabs

Есть image с компонентом Button,есть префаб объекта с функций выстрела. Когда запускаю плеймод,то создается мой объект,как (клон),так и должно,но в ивентах Button он его не видит и соотвество при нажатии объект не стреляет,приходится вручную клон префаба перетаскивать в ивент кнопки и назначить функцию выстрела...тогда все идеально работает,как сделать так чтобы кнопка автоматически находила клоны префаба?

Answer (score -1):

Немного не понял, но вроде и понял что вам нужно:

```
private GameObject _prefabForShot
//ивент кнопки
public void OnClickShot()
{
   _prefabForShot = GameObject.Find("PrefabForShot");
  //ну а дальше соответственно работать с самим геймобжектом по типу
  //_prefabForShot.SetActive(false)
}
```